# docker supervisord cron job not working

Tags: docker, cron, supervisord

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
ADD crontab /root/
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN crontab /root/crontab
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

crontab file:

```
* * * * * echo "Hi" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
#
```

supervisord file:

```
[program:cron]
command=/usr/sbin/cron -f
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/cron.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/cron.log
```

Image info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Host os:
Windows 10

i tried a lot of answers around Stackoverflow but none of them worked, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i replaced this line:

```
ADD crontab /root/
```

with this line:

```
RUN printf '* * * * * echo "Hi" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1\n#' >> /root/crontab
```

It was permission issue when copied from windows to linux env, even though i added `0644` permission for the crontab file, anw, hope it helps someone, i spent hours on this thing